# ошибка swift 5 HELP

Tags: swift

Здравствуй , При конвертации проект на swift 5 выводит такие ошибки .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

вот такие ошибки выводит  помогите пожалуйста

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите код текстом, а не картинкой. Также опишите проблему, в частности: что за ошибку выдаёт.

Answer (score 0):

Соглашайтесь на конвертацию, это не ошибка:

> Compiler warnings 'index(of:)' is deprecated: renamed to
>   'firstIndex(of:)' and 'index(where:)' is deprecated: renamed to
>   'firstIndex(where:) The migrator performs the necessary changes.

Comment: После соглашения выходит это https://ibb.co/f1mK19y

Comment: Это уже другая ошибка. Как вариант, обновите этот файл у разработчика или исправьте ошибку.